# Display selected files in list form

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am using the ngx-dropzone library which allows me to select multiple files.

At this time, the selected files are displayed horizontally but not in the way I want.

Already tried using various types of css and without success, can anyone help me?

[DEMO][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the default styling for ngx-dropzone with some CSS grid styling in order to take effect.

```css
ngx-dropzone {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: auto;
}

ngx-dropzone ngx-dropzone-preview {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This overrides the current default styling and puts the dropped images side by side. See [this updated StackBlitz as example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skwdvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

Result
[image: Stacked dropped images in ngx-dropzone]

The only thing you still need to do is to add styling for the dropped items if the viewport gets bigger.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. There is a way not to increase the size of the box, make the height always fixed. So, for each column I can only add 2 (the ones that fit inside the box), if I add about 10 files, the box gets overflow x active and 5 columns